# System Generated Emails Bouncing Back

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Mail to send system generated emails and am having some of them bounce back.  They do not bounce back when I send from Opera mail.  I am getting the below messages when the emails bounces back.  Does Zend have anything built in that will allow me to send these emails?

**Error Messages**

```
550 Sender verify failed
550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
550 invalid DNS A/AAAA resource record
```

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

The server giving you the bounce response is verifying that your Zend emails are not 'spam' by checking that the Zend sending domain's IP address matches your Zend server's IP address.

You don't have control over the IP address but you do have control over the domain name Zend puts in the email as the sender domain.

To fix this, make sure Zend is configured to send emails using the domain name you desire.

**Checks:**

**1.)** Make sure Zend is set to send from the right domain name.
**2.)** Make sure you have a DNS `A Record`.**3.)** Make sure you have a DNS `MX Record`.

---

The 550 error occurs when the receiving server does a DNS Reverse Lookup to verify that the email senders domain name is aligned with the IP address of the server that sent it.  In this case, it is not.

The last thing, which is already fine if your website works by navigating to the domain name, is to make sure you have an existing DNS `A record` on your domain name that points to the IP address of the server handling requests to the domain.

Another VERY worthwhile DNS record to make sure you have on your domain is a `MX record`.  This should also point to the IP address of the server handling requests to the domain.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I had the dns and mx record set up.  I had success when I changed the transport method to use use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;